# Limit magnify tool in Java to application window only

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, oop

We are trying to modify an existing Java program to be suitable for the visually impaired and one of the changes we are making is a magnification feature.

We have code for magnifying the image underneath the mouse but it affects the whole screen and we want to limit it just to the Java program from which it will be run. E.g. the user clicks on an accesibility menu, then magnify and everything that is under their mouse but only in the application window is magnified rather than everything on their whole screen.

```
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
class magnify extends JFrame { 

// object 
static magnify m; 

// image 
Image i; 

// default constrcutor 
magnify() 
{ 
    // create a frame 
    super("magnify"); 

    // set size of frame 
    setSize(200, 220); 
    show(); 

    // function to magnify the image 
    work(); 
} 

// main function 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 

    // object of class 
    m = new magnify(); 
} 

public void work() 
{ 
    try { 
        // create a robot 
        Robot r = new Robot(); 

        // while the frame is visible 
        while (isVisible()) { 
            // get the position of mouse 
            Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); 

            // create a screen capture around the mouse pointer 
            i = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle((int)p.getX() - 30, 
                                                    (int)p.getY() - 30, 150, 150)); 

            // repaint the conatiner 
            repaint(); 
        } 
        // exit the program 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
} 

// paint function 
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 

    // draw the image 
    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, 300, 300, this); 
} 
}
```

This is the code we are using at the moment found on another post online. The application window is resizeable to fit the screen, much like a native app.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question lacks of significant details. How is the current magnification implemented? What kind of window is it? Are you able to identify the window bounds and restrict magnification to them only? Please, attach a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue and the code you tried to resolve it.

Comment: Hey @BackSlash. Thanks for responding. I added a code sample with further explanations. We are very new to this so your idea of identifying window bounds and restricting magnification is exactly what we are trying to do, but just stuck on how.

Comment: your magnifier 'll at least need to have an instance of the screen/Frame you are trying to magnify. Just because it "sees" a grey pixel, doesn't mean it's part of a JFrame. You might be able to get the borders through that instance, and use those to limit the field to maximize

Comment: @Stultuske. Okay, that sounds like some information to work with for now. Let me do some resesarch and see if I can implement something.